# resolve Invalid persistence.xml

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm working on project with spring jpa hibernate in eclipse. I have an error on my persistence.xml file but I don't know where exactly :

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>

        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am getting error Like this :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'property'.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'mapping-file'. No child element is expected at this point.

    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:46)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:30)
    at org.krams.repository.CustomerDAO.addCustomer(CustomerDAO.java:38)
    at org.krams.repository.CustomerDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$60d23388.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)
```

Could any help me to fix this issue.

Comment: On reading, everything seems ok. The only difference I have in my script (apart from the mapping-file -- we use annotations) is the first line:  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

Comment: Are you using Netbeans? If yes, rename current persistence, and generate a new, to compare. Yesterday I corrected a similar problem using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put mapping file before properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now I am getting this error : `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'property'.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty`

Comment: I have added schemaLocation in root element, can you try it now?